# How do I use BrowserSync in conjunction with OAuth App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, browser-sync

In my case I have a rails app which uses facebook oauth.

Since facebook do not allow for localhost domains to be registered for the OAuth callback URL I am required to use a workaround in development mode. I run the app in development by running the app on port 80 and inserting the following mapping in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1    my-website.com
```

Facebook then redirercts back to `my-website.com/callback` allowing me to authenticate users locally.

So the challenge is to allow for browsersync to livereload js/css at `my-website.com`. I tried configuring gulp and browsersync, with the following

```
proxy: 'my-webite.com'
```

Browsersync then creates a proxy and runs the app on `localhost:3000`. However, upon logging in I am redirected back to `my-website.com` and the browsersync url `localhost:3000` remains in another session and is unable to "login" to my app.

Any suggestions?

(Also tried running my app on port 8000 and browser sync on port 80, however facebook login redirected me to `localhost:8000/callback` which is not a valid redirect URI).